# How to create dynamically chart for Ionic App with Firebase data?

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, chart.js

I have a firebase catalogue as the following for an Ionic 3 app.

These are answers of many users for a questionnaire for each question's id. Most of them have the format of ratings, to wit values 0 to 5. Currently, i get the data and display the mean value for each question from the answers of all users.

> ```
> FIREBASE FORMAT:
>
> -submissions
>  - Jack
>  - George
>  - Peter
>     -0
>         -id: 1.1
>         -rating: 5
>     -1
>         -id: 2.1
>         -rating: 2
>     -2
>     -3
>     -4
>         -id: 3.2
>         -rating: 3
> ```

I create the mean values:

> ```
>  this.submissions = this.afDatabase.list('submissions')
>     var formArray : FormArray = new FormArray([])
>     Array.from(Array(20).keys()).forEach(e => formArray.push(this.createItem()))
>     this.survey = this.formBuilder.group({
>       //rating: [''],
>       //answer: [''],
>       items: this.formBuilder.array(formArray.controls)
>     })
>
>     this.crunchData()
>
>     this.usersubm = this.afDatabase.list('submissions'+`/`+ this.user).valueChanges();
>     this.usersubm.subscribe(_ => {
>       this.loading = false
>     })
>     console.log("usersubm",this.usersubm);
>    // this.apokliseis()
>   }
>
>   ngOnInit() {
>   }
>
>
>
>   crunchData() {
>     this.submissions.valueChanges().subscribe(
>       (results:Submission[]) => {
>         this.loading = false
>         console.log('crunchData.results', results)
>         this.crunch(results)
>       }
>     )    
>   }
>
>   crunch(results: Submission[]) {
>     var stats = {}
>     this.ids = []
>
>     results.forEach((submission) => {
>       var programCode = submission[1].answer
>       var answerArray = submission as QuestionAnswer[]
>
>       if (!stats[programCode]) {
>         stats[programCode] = {}
>         stats[programCode].show = true
>       }
>       answerArray.forEach((answer: QuestionAnswer) => {
>         console.log('answer:', answer.user)
>
>
>
>
>         // include id on list of ids
>         if (this.ids.indexOf(answer.id) == -1) this.ids.push(answer.id)
>
>         if (!stats[programCode][answer.id]) {
>           stats[programCode][answer.id] = {}
>         }
>         var questionStats = stats[programCode][answer.id]
>         questionStats.title = answer.title
>
>         if (answer.type == 'text') {
>           if (!questionStats.answers) questionStats.answers = []
>
>           questionStats.answers.push(answer.answer)
>         }
>
>         // average(statistics[programCode][id].ratings
>         if (answer.type == 'radio') {
>           if (!questionStats.ratings) questionStats.ratings = {}
>           if (!questionStats.ratings[answer.rating]) questionStats.ratings[answer.rating] = 0
>           questionStats.ratings[answer.rating] += 1
>         }
>
>         if (answer.type == 'radio2') {
>           if (!questionStats.answers) questionStats.answers = []
>
>           questionStats.answers.push(answer.answer)
>         }
>
>       })
>     })
>
>     console.log('crunch.stats before', stats)
>     this.statistics = stats
>     this.crunchAverages(results)
>     console.log('crunch.stats', stats)
>     Object.keys(this.statistics).forEach(programCode => {
>       this.ids.forEach(id => {
>
>         this.apant[id]=  this.statistics[programCode][id].answers
>
>         //this.calculateAverage(this.statistics[programCode][id].ratings)
>       })
>     })
>     console.log('apantiseius x:', this.apant[1.1])
>
>
>     this.programCodes = Observable.of( Object.keys(stats))
>     return stats
>
> }
>
>
>   crunchAverages(results: Submission[]) {
>
>     Object.keys(this.statistics).forEach(programCode => {
>       this.ids.forEach(id => {
>         if (id==2.1 || id==3.1 || id==4.1){
>           console.log('gia na doume',  this.statistics[programCode][id].ratings.average)
>         }
>         console.log("id==",id)
>
>         console.log('crunchAverages',  this.statistics[programCode][id])
>         this.calculateAverage(this.statistics[programCode][id].ratings)
>       })
>     })
>
>
>
>   }
>
>
>
>   calculateAverage(ratings) {
>     if (!ratings) return
>     var r1 = ratings[1] ? ratings[1] : 0
>     var r2 = ratings[2] ? ratings[2] : 0
>     var r3 = ratings[3] ? ratings[3] : 0
>     var r4 = ratings[4] ? ratings[4] : 0
>     var r5 = ratings[5] ? ratings[5] : 0
>     var total = r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 + r5
>
>     ratings.average = (1 * r1 + 2 * r2 + 3 * r3 + 4 * r4 + 5 * r5 ) / total
>     ratings.average = Math.round(ratings.average * 1000) / 1000
>     ratings.roundedAverage = this.roundAverage(ratings.average)
>   }
>
>   roundAverage(average: number) {
>     if (average < 0) {
>       console.log('roundAverage warning: average < 0')
>       return 0
>     }
>     if (average < 0.25) return 0.00
>     if (average < 0.75) return 0.50
>     if (average < 1.25) return 1.00
>     if (average < 1.75) return 1.50
>     if (average < 2.25) return 2.00
>     if (average < 2.75) return 2.50
>     if (average < 3.25) return 3.00
>     if (average < 3.75) return 3.50
>     if (average < 4.25) return 4.00
>     if (average < 4.75) return 4.50
>     if (average > 5.00) console.log('roundAverage warning: average > 5')
>     return 5
>   }
>
>   createItem(): FormGroup {
>     return this.formBuilder.group({
>       id: [''],
>       rating: [''],
>       answer: [''],
>       title: ['']
>     })
>   }
> ```

Now, I want to create charts with the average values for each id question so that the average score for each question is visible.

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice Frameworks to create Charts in Ionic. My Favourite one is [ChartJS](https://chartjs.org). You should try it out.